# ASP.NET API with Entity framework6 performace issue

Tags: asp.net, api, entity-framework-6

I have one asp.net api web project ..

The solution is as follows : I have MSSQL DB that have prices for stock market which changes frequently ..I used Entity Framework 6 to handle the inquiries and connections to DB ..

after deployed it on iis 7.5 with windows server 2008 R2. The hits on ASP.NET API is very high ..The server's CPU is going up as image attached ..

Any help will be appreciated ..

[image: CPU Screenshot]

Attached with C# code.
There are three linq queries inside the code ..
Thanks for your hints. I need to know what the key here ..
Any help for that..
[Code C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmh8F.png)

Comment: can you just use Caching somewhere..and are you sure is the DB the issue? ... maybe some not very well engineered c# code?

Comment: No one here can help you with the information you gave. The only recommendation we can give you is to do tests and analyses on each part of your code to find out where the bottleneck is located.

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 v1511 SDK: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771 which is the last version that works in Win7/2008R2), open a cmd.exe as admin and run **wpr.exe -start CPU && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighCPUUsage.etl** while you see the high CPU usage, capture 1-2 minutes before pressing a key to stop capturing. Now analyze the **C:\HighCPUUsage.etl** with WPA: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis

Comment: *I used Entity Framework 6 to handle the inquiries* -- How? There's the key. Show code.

Comment: have you used WPR/WPA to analyze what in detail causes a high CPU usage?

Comment: again, use WPA to see where in detail the CPU is busy. Simply adding code doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Install the WPT (part of the Win10 v1511 SDK: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771 which is the last version that works in Win7/2008R2).

Open a `cmd.exe` as admin and run `wpr.exe -start CPU && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighCPUUsage.etl` while you see the high CPU usage, capture 1-2 minutes before pressing a key to stop capturing.

Now analyze the `C:\HighCPUUsage.etl` with WPA: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/.